# Quick way to check for duplicate arrays within list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list (let's call it `all_my_arrays`) that contains about 48,000 1D arrays. I'd like to know how many duplicate arrays are in this list, if any. However, I'd like to exclude empty arrays (because I have multiple empty arrays within the list and don't want those factored into my duplicate count). I tried this code below, but it is taking too long:

```
import numpy as np
uniques=[]
for arr in all_my_arrays:
    if not np.array_equal(np.array([]), arr):
        if not any(np.array_equal(arr, unique_arr) for unique_arr in uniques):
           uniques.append(arr)
print(len(uniques)) #number of non-duplicates
```

Is there a much quicker way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are these arrays all the same size when they are non-empty?

Comment: Maybe you could sort `all_my_arrays` or a shallow copy of it. Then you only have to compare each array with the previous one to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Yes, the non-empty 1D arrays are all the same size (length of 7).

Comment: *I have a list...* A Python list of numpy arrays? What comprises a duplicate? Is `array([1, 2, 3])` the same as `array([3, 2, 1])`?

Comment: @dawg 1st question: Yes, see the tags. 2nd question: No, duplicate arrays are those which return `True` to `np.array_equal(array1, array2)`, which requires them to be the same length and that every element `array1[i]` and `array2[i]` is the same for each `i` within the range of length.

Comment: @curious_cosmo have you solved this? If so, I think you should mark it as solved so people don't keep posting answers

Comment: @HenryWoody Not yet, I'm still trying these different methods

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `set` type to get the unique values in your list. First you have to convert the arrays to hashable types (tuple here is good). Here's an example:

```
uniques = set(tuple(arr) for arr in all_my_arrays if arr.size > 0)
```

The set `uniques` will contain all the unique, non-empty arrays from your original `all_my_arrays` list. The contents of `uniques` are tuples, but you can convert them back to arrays with a list comprehension. If you're only interested in the number of unique arrays, then you can just call `len(uniques)` and not worry about converting back to arrays.

This approach has time complexity `O(n + m)` where `n` is the number of arrays and `m` is the length of each. There is however the overhead of converting to tuples, but I believe this method should be faster than what you have so far (which has time complexity `O(n^2)`) especially for such a large number of arrays.

**Edit:** To make this a bit faster, you can remove the empty check on each element and then just handle that at the end. Here's what that would look like:

```
uniques = set(tuple(arr) for arr in all_my_arrays)
num_unique = len(uniques) if () not in uniques else len(uniques) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this ran very fast! Does this method preserve order (not required for the purposes of my question, just wondering)?

Comment: @curious_cosmo a set is an unordered collection, so it does not preserve order. You could check out [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (putting tuples as the keys) or [this implementation of OrderedSet](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) if you're interested in preserving order.

Comment: @Alexander the example you've just pointed out (`set(np.matrix([1,2,1,2]))`) is quite different from the solution I have posted. Yours converts the matrix `[1 2 1 2]` into a set `{1, 2}`, while mine converts a comprehension of tuples into a set. So yours is one level beneath what I have described in my answer. A more appropriate example would be `set([np.matrix([1,2,1,2]), np.matrix([1,2,1,3])])`, which produces `{(1,2,1,2), (1,2,1,3)}`, which is actually in line with the question.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
in_arr = np.array([i for i in all_my_arrays if i.size == 7])
uniques = np.unique(in_arr, axis = 0)
uniques_list = list(uniques)  # if you really want a list
```

EDIT: Beware that `np.unique` sorts internally, so order is not preserved.  If you want to maintain order you'll probably need to build a speciality `numba` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NumPy-based solution which may work for you. For simplicity, I'll use an example where arrays are either of length 3 or 0.

Note that count of duplicates as per your definition equals total number of arrays *minus* number of empty arrays *minus* number of unique non-empty arrays.

The last part may be most expensive, but we can use `np.unique` on a regular NumPy array for this:

```
L = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([]), np.array([3, 2, 1]),
     np.array([1, 3, 2]), np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 3, 2]),
     np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]

empty_arr = {idx for idx, arr in enumerate(L) if arr.shape == (0,)}
empty_count = len(empty_arr)

A = np.array([arr for idx, arr in enumerate(L) if idx not in empty_arr])

unique_arr = np.unique(A, axis=0)

duplicates = len(L) - len(empty_arr) - len(unique_arr)

print(duplicates)  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not *sure* that I am understanding your problem fully.

However, if I understand:

1. You have a Python list of 7 element numpy arrays;
2. You want to filter out the arrays that are all `0`;
3. You then want to get a unique count of what is left.

If that is correct, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
li_of_arr=[np.random.choice(4,7) for _ in range(50000)] # example list of arrays
mat=np.array([e for e in li_of_arr if np.any(e)])   # create a numpy matrix of non zero arrays
uniq=np.unique(mat,axis=0)    # here are your unique sub arrays
print (len(mat), len(uniq))   # len of non zero elements and unique non zero elements
```

This takes less than 1 second on my MacBook.